# 15.10 Neither nvidia-304 nor nouveau driver works properly

Tags: nvidia, launcher, nouveau, visual-artifacts

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6100 nForce 400] (rev a2)
```

The default nouveau driver messes up the dash launcher. Clicking on the dash icon causes visual artifacts to appear on the desktop

[image: screen with orange/green bar]

Eventually the screen freezes altogether and I have to do a hard-reset.

When I try using nvidia-304 from **Additional Drivers**, it is even worse. Basically the whole desktop freezes like this

[image: dash icons distorted, rest of screen black]

I can switch to another tty and reboot.

How should go about solving with either driver?

I've tried unity-tweak-tool and disabling some stuff like animations and blurred launcher bg, but it did not help.